# What is S/PDIF Port on Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, audio-hardware

How does the S/PDIF Port work? If it can be used with RCA Adapter, how would I connect the cables from the VGA HD AV cable?

Answer (score 5):

[S/PDIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/?title=S/PDIF) stands for **Sony/Philips Digital Interface Format** and carries audio data over either an optical (TOSLINK) or an electrical (coaxial) cable.

The Xbox 360 uses TOSLINK cables for its S/PDIF interface. TOSLINK ports are covered by a plastic door - usually black - which is meant to protect from dirt.

[image: Picture of Xbox 360 adapter with TOSLINK port]

Plugging a TOSLINK cable in a TOSLINK port is as easy as plugging a USB cable in a USB port, since the plastic cover does not hinder the cable from reaching the port.

When powered, a TOSLINK port will emit red light, which can be visible through the black plastic cover.

Comment: so i can use speakers or something?

Comment: @oStarZ If the speaker has a TOSLINK port, yes. You obviously can't just directly plug your 3.5mm headphone jack into a TOSLINK port. You'll either need a TV with TOSLINK port, or a HIFI system that supports TOSLINK S/PDIF. Be warned, that S/PDIF (TOSLINK) is ***not*** compatible to S/PDIF (coax).

Comment: @oStarZ Almost all home theatre amps and many other home stereo amps have one or more TOSLINK inputs.  Some TVs will also have a TOSLINK input, but it's generally wasted on them since they can only produce stereo sound, and TOSLINK is generally used for 5.1 surround sound.  TVs will usually have a TOSLINK output so that you can patch a 5.1 coming from the cable/antenna input into your home theatre amp.  Without more details about what your setup is like, it sounds like TOSLINK isn't an option for you.  Stick to the stereo RCA cables.